# Powershell Command in Windows Server 2019 Task Scheduler?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a Powershell task to start automatically after Windows starts (to restart a process in case of a crash or maintenance). My knowledge of Powershell is very limited, but when I manually want to start the task, I need to go to the folder in Explorer, and open Powershell from there which defaults me to "PS C:\Users{{username}}\Documents\fso\fso> " where I then type in "./watchdog.bat". In trying to setup Task Scheduler, it seems like it's looking for a .ps1 file which I have no knowledge of. Would someone mind helping me with this?

Much thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Working directory" for the task action to `C:\Users{{username}}\Documents\fso\fso`?

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest. From what I found through Google searches and similar posts to mine, I created a task "action" to "start a program". For program I've done "powershell.exe" and then put C:\Users\{{username}}\Documents\fso\fso in "Start In". Would that be correct? I'm not sure where I would enter the command "./watchdog.bat". Would that be the argument?

Comment: Great, then you just need to add a command or file to run, in the "Add arguments" field, either put `-Command './watchdog.bat'` or `-File "C:\path\to\script.ps1"`, where `script.ps1` would be a powershell script calling `watchdog.bat`

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can post it as answer to close this issue.

Comment: Hi, I have post the solution. Can you [mark it as the answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png) of this question? This will help others who meet the similar problem. :) Also you can post yourself answer, if you do that please let me know and then I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Mathias R. Jessen's help,

The solution is add a command or file to run, in the "Add arguments" field, either put `-Command './watchdog.bat'` or `-File "C:\path\to\script.ps1"`, where `script.ps1` would be a powershell script calling `watchdog.bat`